# List of users to match a list of job titles in AD

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a list of Job titles in a csv file and need to match these to whichever user has the title in AD.

CSV Contents is like this:

```
JobTitle1
JobTitle2
JobTitle3
```

The following command will work to get a list of all users with the `JobTitle1` title:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Title -like 'JobTitle1'"
```

However I can't get this to work with the CSV file as an array, it doesnt return any output:

```
$Titles = Get-Content -Path "c:\jobtitles.csv"  
ForEach ($Title In $Titles)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Title -like '$Title'} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell a variable within *single quotes doesn't get populated* so you have to use **double quotes** instead -  or just **omit** them:

```
$Titles = Get-Content -Path "c:\jobtitles.csv"  
ForEach ($Title In $Titles)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter {Title -like $Title} 
}
```